# Yii2 createCommand with params

Tags: mysql, count, yii2

I need count my cart items in db, cart items without model. Trying like this:

```
$id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
$total = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart_items WHERE user_id="'.$id.'"')->queryScalar();
```

Return 0, but have 2 rows.

```
$total = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart_items WHERE user_id="19"')->queryScalar();
```

Return 2.

How to bind my params right with post data?

Update:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)){
            Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [            
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'checkout' => ['post','get'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Let me guess. You've forgot to mention that you are sending the id in HTTP request as json in request's body, right?

Comment: Yeap, its little rest api for mobile app, before action for json response back

Comment: That's the reason why `Yii::$app->request->post('id');` returns null. By default only fields from `$_POST` are available through `Yii::$app->request->post()` and JSON is not parsed into $_POST variable. You need to add [JSON parser](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-jsonparser) if you want to access values from JSON request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use bindValues()

```
  $total = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM cart_items WHERE user_id=:id')
    ->bindValues([':id'=>$id])
    ->queryScalar();
```

Comment: This solution not working too,  i checked if post requests are coming to the action, all post return null. I use Postman with post request for testing. In beforeAction i set $this->enableCsrfValidation = false; but not work

Comment: I have added more information to the question

Comment: answer  updated ..  request->post() normally return an array

Comment: Undefined index: id, post data not come in action

Comment: then try check the real content for Yii::$app->request->post() and assign the proper value .. answer updated ..  without array

Comment: the mystic is that any post data is not transferred to the action, all value is null, CsrfValidation validation disabled, where is my issue?

Comment: update your question and add  the view/form code ..could be  you have not a proper active form in your code

Comment: i dont have view or form, only action, its simple rest api

Comment: are you sure you are sending using post and not using get method??

Comment: you are going to scream now, i put my request params in Params tab, post request use Body params. I am using this software for the first time and I thought that it was enough to specify the request type. Ur solution now work, thank you man!